# Problem using \\d inside a user-defined character class

Tags: r, regex

I'm struggling to understand why I seem unable to include a shorthand character class such as `\\d` or `\\w` **inside a user-defined character class** between `[`and `]` (although I have seen cases where such an inclusion can be done). What I want to do in this illustrative example is relocate the currency symbol from the right end of the string to the start of the string:

```
a_1 <- c("155.88¥","5156.04€","656","1566.1$")

sub("([\\w.]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1)   # doesn't work
sub("([\\d.]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1)   # doesn't work
sub("([0-9.]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1)   # works
```

Why does only the fully user-defined character class work but not those that involve the shorthand character classes?

**Expected result:**

```
[1] "¥155.88"  "€5156.04" "656"      "$1566.1"
```

Comment: the character classes `\\w`, `\\s`, `\\d` etc come from `perl`, so when you use those make sure to add `perl = T` in your code :)

Comment: Ah YES! That's the solution! Thank you for this clarification. Please consider posting this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

Character classes such as `\\d`, `\\s`, `\\w` are from `Perl` so when you use those make sure to add `perl = T` in your code.

For example:

```
sub("([\\w.]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1, perl = T)
```

More information can be found here:

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of R's regex flavor, which is POSIX.  [See here](https://github.com/micromatch/posix-character-classes) that POSIX does not allow `\d` inside a character class but instead must use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.  According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html):

> There are a number of pre-built classes that you can use inside []:

```
[:punct:]: punctuation.
[:alpha:]: letters.
[:lower:]: lowercase letters.
[:upper:]: upperclass letters.
[:digit:]: digits.
... (and others)
```

Consider:

```
a_1 <- c("155.88¥","5156.04€","656","1566.1$")
sub("([[:digit:].]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1)

[1] "¥155.88" "€5156.04" "656" "$1566.1"
```

But note that if we run `sub` in Perl mode, which is PCRA regex, then `\d` inside a character class works:

```r
a_1 <- c("155.88¥","5156.04€","656","1566.1$")
sub("([\\d.]+)([€$¥])", "\\2\\1", a_1, perl=TRUE)

[1] "¥155.88" "€5156.04" "656" "$1566.1"
```

Perhaps the places where you remember seeing `\d` inside a character class were using Perl PCRA mode.

Comment: Are these the only ones in R? I've seen `\\w` and `\\s` inside []

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes, there are many other predefined character classes, check the link in my answer.  The answer to your question is that R's regex flavor behaves this way.

Comment: I have checked the link and I know that there are many predefined char classes. The link does not explicitly state that, e.g., `\\d` cannot be used inside []. And to reiterate, I've seen cases in R where it could be done, at least with `\\s` and `\\w`